# Cant connect to Mysql docker container from host

Tags: mysql, docker

Im running docker on windows and I start up a docker container with MySql like this

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret-pw -d mysql/mysql-server:5.5
```

Then on my host I start up Mysql workbench and try to connect but it does not work.

`docker inspect test` reveal IP address on 172.17.0.2 but when I ping this I get no reply

Got this working on a linux host and I am pretty sure I have done the exact same steps

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 9):

Help Doc: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/

Image link: https://store.docker.com/images/mysql

**Command:** `docker run --name mysql_container_name  --expose=3306 -p 3306 -v /my/own/datadir:/path/to/data/dir -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_pwd -d mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

- `mysql_container_name`: docker container name
- `expose`: contaner exposeing port
- `p`: host buinding port
- `/path/to/data/dir`: share path between container and host
- `root_pwd`: mysql root password
- `tag`: repository tag
- `utf8mb4`: mysql server character set and collation type
- `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`: mysql server character set and collation type

**Example:** `docker run --expose=3306 -p 3306 --name mysql -v /my/own/datadir:/opt/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=0112358139 -d mysql:latest --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

**Following steps to connect remotely:**

```
docker exec -it mydb bash  --> this will connect to mySql container. 

echo "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf   --> this will update the my.cnf file. 

service mysql restart --> restart the mySql service. 

exit --> the mySql container. 

docker inspect mysql | grep IPAddress --> grep the IP address of the contaner. 

mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root –p  --> remotely connect to the mySql.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your host 3306 port should be forwarding to the container, so try connecting on localhost:3306. When I tried to replicate, got the "Host 172.17.0.1 not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" which means it got through at least.

More on the latter: https://github.com/fideloper/docker-mysql/issues/10